# how to make a pic from menu file as a link?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i made a menu in which are included some pictures, and i want them to be a link, but all i can do is to make only the text as a link!
the text is located in the top of the pic's, so when i mouseover in the pictures, it's not like a link..link appears only when i put the mouse over the text on the top of the pic..
i want to make all the pic as a link, not only the text,
i guess i've put in the wrong place the a href
anyway, here is the code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mbcsmbur9s.css" type="text/css" />


<ul id="mbur9sebul_table" class="mbur9sebul_menulist css_menu" style="width: 931px; height:  165px;">
  <li class="topitem spaced_li"><div class="buttonbg gradient_button gradient165"><div class="icon_1"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/RealMadrid?fref=ts">Facebook</a></div></div></li>
  <li class="topitem spaced_li"><div class="buttonbg gradient_button gradient165"><div class="icon_2"><a>Twitter</a></div></div></li>
  <li class="topitem spaced_li"><div class="buttonbg gradient_button gradient165"><div class="icon_3"><a>Google +</a></div></div></li>
  <li class="topitem spaced_li"><div class="buttonbg gradient_button gradient165"><div class="icon_4"><a>Youtube</a></div></div></li>
  <li class="topitem spaced_li"><div class="buttonbg gradient_button gradient165"><div class="icon_5"><a>Android</a></div></div></li>
  <li class="topitem"><div class="buttonbg gradient_button gradient165" style="width: 184px;"> <div class="icon_6"><a>iOS</a></div></div></li>
</ul>
<!-- Menus will work without this javascript file. It is used only for extra
     effects, improved usability and compatibility with very old web browsers. -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="mbjsmbur9s.js"></script>
```

Comment: you can also give background image for <div class="icon_5"> and position it using background position

Comment: yeah, but i dont want a background image, i need it to be transparent, because looks better on the page in that way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the image in the a-tag. And add href attribute like:

```
<a href='#'><img src='your-image.png' />Twitter</a>
```

**EDIT:** Because of the conversation below: `<a href='#' class='icon_3'>Twitter</a`> and in your CSS it has to look like this:

```
.icon_3 {
  display: block;
  background-image: url('ebab_mbur9s_ico_2.png'); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat; 
  background-position: center 28px; 
  height: 100%; 
}
```

It is necessary to use `display: block;` because an anchor is an inline element basically. Do this with all your icon classes. You may have to edit the actual background position.

Comment: oh i did it and it worked, but theres a problem, there are 2 pictures now o.O
look: http://i.imgur.com/rEGyDG8.jpg

Comment: @Frank I guess you set it as background image with CSS **AND** with an img-tag, is that right? If so, remove the css one.

Comment: this code: <div class="icon_2" is getting the image and showing it, so instead of <a href='#'><img src='your-image.png' />Twitter</a>
i think we should make the <div class="icon_2" as a link..but how exactly i do it because im trying and i dont get it

Comment: you mean to add the <div class="icon_2"> instead if the img src? im a little bit confused

Comment: @Frank No, I meant to do following `<a href='#' class='icon_2'>` so your link will take the same styles as your icon did. But as long as I don't know what properties your icon_2 class has set, there can be some problems. Could you add it to your question?

Comment: okay, i did it but didnt work, i dont know maybe im doing something wrong, im not too sure, i just uploaded all the menu files in rar, so it's easier for you all to help me, take a better look:
http://www.filedropper.com/menu3

Comment: @Frank In your CSS file ( line 251 for example ) you're writing `div.icon_3` that's why it doesn't work on an a-tag. Remove `div` and add `display: block` then it should work.

Comment: ok so on the line 251 i replaced the: #mbur9sebul_table div.icon_3 { 
with this: #mbur9sebul_table display: block.icon_3 { ..
i'm sorry but now what exactly i must change to the code, because i dont get result?
does it work correctly on you?

Comment: indeed, this worked, but the position of the text and of the image had changed..anyway i fixed the position of the pic by img style and the text by <p style=...etc..Your code works just like Mike's code!
Thank You both! :)

Comment: @Frank Mike's solution was my first answer ;) I'm glad it works.

Comment: when i put the code of text:
<p style="position: fixed; top: 20px; left:215px; text-align: center">Twitter</p></a></div></li>
i get this: http://i.imgur.com/IYKBChP.jpg
this text needs to be placed on the top of the logo picture, not in the top of page lol, if i edit again it's position, it will look good only for one page :S, i need it to be right in the top of the picture logo every time..what's wrong in my code?

Comment: hey, i want to add an effect on mouse over..
i want the Morph style from here: http://designshack.net/articles/css/joshuajohnson-2/
but where exactly i must put the code in CSS file? there are 280 lines in CSS file :S

Comment: @Frank there are tutorials for each animation on this site. WHERE you place your code in your CSS file, is in most cases not relevant.

Comment: oh that's it :D these effects are amazing, thank you :D

Comment: hey bro, can you take a look in my other question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166111/how-to-show-a-content-only-in-the-home-page-and-not-in-the-categories

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<li class="topitem spaced_li"><div class="buttonbg gradient_button gradient165"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/RealMadrid?fref=ts"><div class="icon_1"></div></a></div></li>
```

Comment: i did it, all the picture is good as a link now but there appears 2 little problems now:
1 the pictures has moved a little down, it's not in the same exact position like others- http://i.imgur.com/mhajXHs.jpg
2 the Facebook header is not included..it should be like this - http://i.imgur.com/5wNfWT6.jpg :/

Comment: i uploaded my menu here, as it was from the beginning, i hope it's bit easier for you to solve this problem now:
http://www.filedropper.com/menu3

Answer (score 0):

you can give a background-image for `<a>`

eg : check this js fiddle

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/mq1780qm/1/)

```
a {
    display:block;
    background:url('xxx.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: 25px 25px;
    padding:10px 10px 10px 35px;
    background-position: center left;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: check the fiddle it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

You would surround your img with the "< a>" (anchor) tag.

```html
<ul style='list-style:none'>
  <li><a href='#'><img style='position:relative; top:-15px; left:50px;' height='50px' width='50px' src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-large-twitter-icons/512/Twitter_button.png"/>Twitter</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hmm, i guess i must define by myself where the pic will appear exactly, i got a little trouble with the text too because it was in another position but i fixed it with the <p style=....etc..
Your code worked thanks! :)

Comment: but a little problem with the text appears,
when i put the code of text: <p style="position: fixed; top: 20px; left:215px; text-align: center">Twitter</p></a></div></li> i get this: i.imgur.com/IYKBChP.jpg this text needs to be placed on the top of the logo picture, not in the top of page lol, if i edit again it's position, it will look good only for one page :S, i need it to be right in the top of the picture logo every time..what's wrong?